# GlobalConfiguration not found after updating to Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 5.2.3 and Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost 3.2.4

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ninject, owin

I am working on a web application which uses Owin hosting for both MVC and WebApi 2.

I recently the Microsoft Mvc/WebApi packages from version 5.2.2 to version 5.2.3, and the Owin packages from version 3.0.0 to 3.0.1, however this caused problems with Ninject, which was at 3.2.3.

I updated Ninject.Web.WebApi to version 3.2.4 and installed Ninject.Web.WebApi (also at version 3.2.4) following compilation errors with it not recognising GlobalConfiguration.

This compiled, but when I ran it, I got the error:

*Error activating HttpConfiguration
More than one matching bindings are available.
Matching bindings:
 1) binding from HttpConfiguration to method
 2) binding from HttpConfiguration to constant value
Activation path:
 1) Request for HttpConfiguration
Suggestions:
 1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for HttpConfiguration only once.*

The only place I was creating and adding HttpConfiguration was in the Owin Startup configuration,  Configuration(IAppBuilder app).

I have since undone all my changes and tried to re-install all the packages. This time I have the error that GlobalConfiguration cannot be saved, so I don't know if there is an order dependency when updating the packages. (I have installed Ninject.Web.WebApi as recommended by the [release notes](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.WebApi/blob/master/ReleaseNotes.md), but I still get the compilation error about GlobalConfiguration.)

I have looked through the dependencies of Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost and cannot see anything which suggests it should not work with Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 5.2.3 etc. or Microsoft.Owin 3.0.1 etc. Is there a known issue with this?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why this was giving the error was because of the Ninject packages, but NuGet packages which depended on Ninject which were still using old versions. Updating all the NuGet packages which depended on Ninject fixed this issue.